# This program cannot be run in dos mode что делать

Tags: ассемблер

По заданию мне надо его скомпоновать и но на этапе линковки выдаёт ошибку

> This program cannot be run in dos mode

что делать подскажите как решить

```
asm
.486
.model flat, stdcall
option casemap :none ; case sensitive
include windows.inc
include user32.inc
include kernel32.inc
includelib user32.lib
includelib kernel32.lib

.data
szTitle db "Message", 0
szMessage db "Hello, World!", 0
.code
start:
push MB_OK + MB_ICONINFORMATION
push offset szTitle
push offset szMessage
push 0
call MessageBox
push 0
call ExitProcess
end start
```

Comment: Рассказывайте, как собираете, как линкуете, как запускаете.

Comment: ml.exe /c /coff program.asm
link.exe /subsystem:windows program.obj выдаёт ошибку - This program cannot be run in DOS mode.

Comment: всё делал в дос боксе установил masm32

Comment: Так не используйте досбокс, в 2023 это ни к чему.  /subsystem:windows  - это обычное десктопное приложение.

Comment: а как тогда спомлировать

Comment: ¿что значит спомлировать?